# Retrieving Column from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How to get values from one column of HTML table using JavaScript?

I want to get values of one field i.e one column from the HTML table which is dynamically created.

Comment: Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgDh/).

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery you can use this plugin

```
$.fn.getColumn = function(column) {
    return this.find('tr').map(function() {
        return $(this).find('td').eq(column).text();
    }).get();
};
```

using:

```
$('table').getColumn(1);
```

Without jQuery it will be

```
function getColumn(selector, column) {
    var rows = document.querySelector(selector).getElementsByTagName('tr');
    return [].slice.call(rows).map(function(tr) {
        return tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[column].innerText;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the table dynamically you must be assigning some id to table, so try this:

```
var allTDs = document.getElementById('<TableId>').getElementsByTagName('TD');
var valueNeeded = allTDs[0].innerHTML;
```

If you want to get the values of all the first columns in all the rows the use this:

```
var allTRs = document.getElementById('<TableId>').getElementsByTagName('TR');
for(var i = 0; i < allTRs .length; i++)
{
    //This is a loop so store the value of each TD or column wherever you want to  
    var valueNeeded = allTDs.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by jcubic's answer. This functional approach also works with tables that have a header row.

```js
[].slice
  .call(document.querySelector('table').getElementsByTagName('tr'))
  .map(tr => tr.getElementsByTagName('td'))
  .filter(tr => tr.length > 0)
  .map(tr => tr[column_index].innerText);
```